.Net MAUI Map elements Tabbed event
i am working on .net maui map, drawing circles using mapElement but struggling to find the an event/command that triigers when clicked on a circle.
In xamarin forms we handle circle element cliked
              //Xamarin Code
                              var c = new Circle()
                                {
                                    Center = new Position(37.79752, -122.40183),
                                    Radius = new Distance(200),
                                    StrokeWidth = 0,
                                    FillColor = Color.FromHex("#88FFC0CB")
                                };
                                c.Clicked += (sn, ea) =>
                                {
                                    ShowStoreInfo(Convert.ToInt32(((Circle)sn).Tag));
                                };
                                map.Circles.Add(c);

In .net maui i was unable to find the clicked event
              //.Net maui code
                            Circle circle = new Circle
                            {
                               Center = new Location(37.79752, -122.40183),
                               Radius = new Distance(200),
                               StrokeWidth = 0,
                               FillColor = Color.FromArgb("#88FFC0CB")
                            };
                           map.MapElements.Add(circle);




add a GestureRecognizer

@Jason, thanks for your response. I tried to add a GestureRecognizer, but it doesn’t seem to allow me to add the gesture. It looks like we can't add GestureRecognizer to map elements.

You may try adding a MapClicked event handler and check if the coordinates are in the Circle.

You can set the GestureRecognizer for the Map. Then you can write the method to the TapGestureRecognizer.
  public MainPage()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      TapGestureRecognizer tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
      tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) =>
      {
          // Handle the tap
      };

      Map map = new Map();

      // Instantiate a Circle
      Circle circle = new Circle
      {
          Center = new Location(37.79752, -122.40183),
          Radius = new Distance(250),
          StrokeColor = Color.FromArgb("#88FF0000"),
          StrokeWidth = 8,
          FillColor = Color.FromArgb("#88FFC0CB")
      };

      map.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

      // Add the Circle to the map's MapElements collection
      map.MapElements.Add(circle);

  }


Also don't work in current .net maui 8  I did not get the tap on a map. Are there other ways ? Custom Handler ? Any code samples ?
